# Creating libraries with JavaScript - ES 6

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6

I am building an app using Node and ES6. This app has a library that I want to use across projects. For the sake of this question, the directory structure of the library looks like this:

```
lib
  logging
    logManager.js
    logEntry.js
  security
    user.js
    role.js
```

My actual structure is different. I chose `logging` and `security` to make the question more approachable. Still, my code currently looks like this:

**logManager.js**

```
'use strict';

var User = require('../security/user.js');
class LogManager {
  constructor(props) {
    this.user = props.user;
  }
}
module.exports LogManager;
```

**logEntry.js**

```
'use strict';
class LogEntry {
  constructor(props) {
  }
}
module.exports LogEntry;
```

**user.js**

```
'use strict';
class User {
  constructor(props) {
  }
}
module.exports User;
```

**role.js**

```
'use strict';
class Role {
  constructor(props) {
  }
}
module.exports Role;
```

My mind set may be in the object-oriented Java / C# worlds. However, I'm trying to figure out how to package these four files into a single file I can distribute. In an attempt to do this, I have added a gulp task that looks like this:

```
gulp.task('package', function() {
    return gulp.src(input.js)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))       
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(concat(output.js))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    ;    
});
```

This task puts all four files into a file called `dist/library.js`. However, I have several issues. First, JSHint complains about the use of strict in each of my files. So, I removed the 'use strict' lines just for the sake of trying to move forward and getting by JSHint (which I don't want to do). But I feel I'm really off on something because when the concatenation happens, the `require` statement in `logManager.js` breaks.

It feels like everything works as individual components. However, when I attempt to bundle them altogether into library.js, it breaks. What am I missing?

Comment: "What am I missing?" MB equals sign `module.exports = LogManager;`?

Comment: Check my project template, it is far from 100%, but maybe it helps to solve your problem: https://github.com/inf3rno/javascript-project-template/tree/babel You should use export and import in ES6.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your module exports.

```
// this is wrong syntax (missing "=")
module.exports LogManager;
```

As you already use babel, you could switch over ES6-modules

```
// default export of module (ES6 syntax)
export default LogManager;

// importing modules (ES6 syntax)
import User from 'security/user';
```

Comment: So, are you recommending I `import User from 'security/user' in myLibrary.js?

Comment: as Yury Tarabanko commented your export syntax is wrong. You can fix it and use commonJS modules or by using ES6 module syntax